# How to send mail notification from jboss server after server down or stopped working?

Tags: jboss

I want to send mail b **Jboss** server when server **down** , stop working or there is any unexpected **crash** in server

Comment: I am using Jboss 4.2.3

Answer (score 0):

If jboss is down then it can't send email.  Because it is down

So you need to monitor it with a different system.

Nagios is a widely open source monitoring system http://www.nagios.org  It has a lot of plugins that can be configured to monitor jboss according to your exact business needs

Comment: thanks Vorsprung :) But I have read on jboss community these lines- Under JBoss AS 5.1.0.GA it was possible to make use of the JMX Log Appender (org.jboss.monitor.services.JMXNotificationAppender) and

subsequently the JBoss JMX Notifications/Alarms/Alerts/etc (org.jboss.monitor.*), in order to handle warnings, errors and shutdown; i.e. selectively

forward the information to users via email, snmp, rss, etc. But not able to understand the way it is doing.